# install IBM Big insights 3.0.0.0, the Big SQL component error and can not start

Tags: bigdata, biginsights, bigsql

When I install IBM Big Insights Quick Start Editor 3.0.0.0, other components are correct except the Big SQL component that has an error:

> can not start the Big SQL Head Node and Big SQL Scheduler Nodes .

When I　run `./start.sh bigsql` in `<BIGINSIGHTS_HOME>/bin`

```
Starting Big SQL Scheduler     : FAIL
   ** Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.scheduler.server.SchedulerConfiguration
   ** Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.scheduler.server.SchedulerConfiguration
   **   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
   **   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
   **   at sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
   **   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
   ** Could not find the main class: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.scheduler.server.SchedulerConfiguration.  Program will exit.
   ** Big SQL scheduled startup failed. See /bi/var/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/logs/bigsql-sched.out for details
```

Get following error when in run `./bigsql start` in `<BIGINSIGHTS_HOME>/bigsql/bin`

```
[bigsql@dpev210 bin]$ ./bigsql start
Starting Big SQL Scheduler     : FAIL
   ** Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.scheduler.server.SchedulerConfiguration
   ** Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.scheduler.server.SchedulerConfiguration
   **   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
   **   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
   **   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
   **   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
   ** Could not find the main class: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.scheduler.server.SchedulerConfiguration.  Program will exit.
   ** Big SQL scheduled startup failed. See /bi/var/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/logs/bigsql-sched.out for details
Starting Big SQL      FAIL
   ** ssh "dpev210.innovate.sfb.com" "bash -l -c \"/bi/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/libexec/bigsql-start\"
   ** WARNING: Cannot locate /bi/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install/bigsql-install.conf
   ** Running: db2start
   ** 06/30/2014 10:45:12     0   0   SQL6048N  A communication error occurred during START or STOP DATABASE MANAGER processing.
   ** 06/30/2014 10:45:13     1   0   SQL1026N  The database manager is already active.
   ** SQL6032W  Start command processing was attempted on "2" node(s).  "0" node(s) were successfully started.  "1" node(s) were already started.  "1" node(s) could not be started.
Starting Big SQL v1            : OK (Already running (pid 3405897))
```

Answer (score 3):

Have not find any tips in the official document ,but can fixed it by following :

run command :./bigsql-setup.sh in /opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install

```
[bigsql@dpev210 install]$ ./bigsql-setup.sh
Logging output to: /bi/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install/bigsql-setup-140630105118.log

Disabling Big SQL functionality          : OK
Processing log config templates          : OK
Configuring OPTIMIZED native I/O         : OK
Creating bigsql-conf.xml                 : OK
Performing slave pre-flight setup
   dpev209.innovate.ibm.com              : OK
Starting DB2 (if necessary)              : OK
Entering DEFAULT instance mode           : OK
Creating database BIGSQL                 :
OK
Cataloging database BIGSQL on slaves
   dpev209.innovate.ibm.com              : OK
Installing support DDL                   : OK (in SYSHADOOP)
Configuring FMP logging                  : OK
Updating database manager config         : OK
Configuring database BIGSQL storage      : OK
Enabling Big SQL mode                    : OK
Closing DB2 connections                  : OK
Stopping DB2 instance                    : OK
Generating userprofile                   : OK
Enabling Big SQL mode                    : OK
Finalizing slave setup
   dpev209.innovate.ibm.com              : OK
Starting DB2 instance                    : OK

Setup is complete. Log file can be found at /bi/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install/bigsql-setup-140630105118.log.
```

after ran above command ,the Big SQL server will be up .

Answer (score 1):

First try running the BigSql again by doing following commands:
1.  Go to the folder : $HOME/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install
2.  And then run the command :     #./bigsql-setup.sh
The bigsql might get installed now, but I got the setup failed at creating database.
The problem occurs for the following reasons:
1.  The file permissions not set properly to create the database at particular location.
2.  The mounting of the files is done.

For the file permissions:
1.  Go to:  /home/biadmin/var/ibm/biginsights/database/bigsql  and change the permissions of the directory to 777 in all the blades by running the command.

## chmod –R 777  bigsql

Again try running bigsql. Go to the folder: $HOME/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install
And then run the command:     #./bigsql-setup.sh
I got setup failed again, and appeared below:
Creating  Database Bigsql : Error

SQL1005N  The database alias "BIGSQL" already exists in either the local
database directory or system database directory.

then I tried running the below command logging as bigsql user:

## db2 catalog DATABASE BIGSQL    and reboot all the blades.

Again try running bigsql. Go to the folder: $HOME/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install
And then run the command:     #./bigsql-setup.sh
Now, I got the setup success and appear like below:
[bigsql@dpev210 install]$ ./bigsql-setup.sh
Logging output to: /bi/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install/bigsql-setup-140630105118.log

Disabling Big SQL functionality          : OK
Processing log config templates          : OK
Configuring OPTIMIZED native I/O         : OK
Creating bigsql-conf.xml                 : OK
Performing slave pre-flight setup
   dpev209.innovate.ibm.com              : OK
Starting DB2 (if necessary)              : OK
Entering DEFAULT instance mode           : OK
Creating database BIGSQL                 :
OK
Cataloging database BIGSQL on slaves
   dpev209.innovate.ibm.com              : OK
Installing support DDL                   : OK (in SYSHADOOP)
Configuring FMP logging                  : OK
Updating database manager config         : OK
Configuring database BIGSQL storage      : OK
Enabling Big SQL mode                    : OK
Closing DB2 connections                  : OK
Stopping DB2 instance                    : OK
Generating userprofile                   : OK
Enabling Big SQL mode                    : OK
Finalizing slave setup
   dpev209.innovate.ibm.com              : OK
Starting DB2 instance                    : OK

Setup is complete. Log file can be found at /bi/opt/ibm/biginsights/bigsql/install/bigsql-setup-140630105118.log.

Now, I started all the processes. Go to folder:  $HOME/opt/ibm/biginsights/bin/
And running the command:  # ./start-all.sh
as biadmin user.
 Now, checking the IBM console I got the bigsql running.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and then I tried your solution. 
But while I was trying your solution, the setup was not able to complete and was giving error at step.

```
Creating  Database Bigsql : Error

SQL1005N  The database alias "BIGSQL" already exists in either the local
database directory or system database directory.
```

I resolved it by cataloging the BIGSQL database using

```
db2 catalog database BIGSQL
```

Link:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3JRN_7.2.0/com.ibm.itcamsoa.doc/kd4trmst32.htm%23wq38

After cataloging it, it becomes available during bigsql-setup and succeeds.